# Error installing Mysql-5.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS even after completely removing MYSQL

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have removed the Mysql5.7 and trying to reinstall it in Ubuntu 16.04.

I followed the below procedure n times, still facing the same issue:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql.*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Resinstall mysql:

sudo apt-get install mysql-server --fix-missing --fix-broken
```

I get 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:

[image]

Comment: check the package still available using  dpkg -l | grep mysql if yes, remove completely using dpkg --purge <package name> & check.

Comment: if i purge for the grep'ed mysql, i get dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-core-5.7 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-core-5.7 and for others

Comment: Check out links:
[16.04 upgrade broke mysql-server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server)

[Cannot reinstall mysql-server after its purge](http://askubuntu.com/questions/763534/cannot-reinstall-mysql-server-after-its-purge)